# How to speed up reading 2 tsv files and writing them as a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have a tsv file of tweets with 13 columns, each row representing a tweet (total of ~300M tweets). Also have another tsv file with 3 columns including userinfo (~500Mb). I need to read both files and put all columns of the tweet file and the second column of the userinfo file together and save them as a JSON file for each tweet. I've written the following code, but its very very slow. I was wondering whether there is a way to speed it up.

Here is my code:

```
t_dic = {}
with open("~/userinfo_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split('\t')
        uid = data[0]
        user_info = data[1]
        user_info_dic = json.loads(user_info)
        t_dic[uid] = user_info_dic
f.close()


with open('~/tweets_file.txt') as f:
    for data in f:
        line = data.split('\t')
        user_dic = {}
        uid = line[0].strip()
        if uid in t_dic.keys(): # check whether the user is in my userinfo list
            user_dic['id'] = line[1].strip()
            user_dic['id_str'] = str(line[1].strip())
            user_dic['text'] = line[2].decode('utf-8').strip()
            user_dic['created_at'] = line[3].strip()
            user_dic['user'] = t_dic[uid] # here Im using the above dic which I created based on the userinfo file

            with io.open("~/tweet_dir/{}.json".format(user_dic['id']),'a') as f2:
                f2.write(unicode(json.dumps(user_dic)))
            f2.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Creating a different file for each tweet will be expensive in time and space (each file occupy typically 4Kb). A better design would be to put all in a single database table.

Which OS/file system do you use ? Why do you need each tweet in a different file ?

Comment: I'm using a package which requires each tweet in a JSON file. I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried running it without the file creation? That should tell us if that the slow part. Do you need that files persist?

Comment: @memoselyk: Yes I did. Doesn't make any difference. The main cause is opening the userinfo file and adding its second column to the final JSON file.

Comment: As pointed out by the answer from [Karl Barker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1226028/karl-barker) the only right way to know why is slow is profiling your code.

Comment: BTW... `f.close()` is not required when using the `with` statement, the context manager will close the file for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only *inefficient* that I can spot is:

```
if uid in t_dic.keys(): # check whether the user is in my userinfo list
```

Note the difference with,

```
if uid in t_dic: # check whether the user is in my userinfo list
```

The first one is doing a search in a list of items, which is not optimized for searching, while the later is searching in a set which should have better performance for searches.

Answer (score 1):

You can profile the time your program spends on each line using the [Python profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) `cProfile` and `profile`. 
Run `cProfile` on your script using:

```
python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] myscript.py
```